# Integral of meromorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be meromorphic function in $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ with a pole $z=z_0$. Then, is it true that there is a number $N$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_C f(z)(z-z_0)^{n-1}dz=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_C f(z)(z-z_0)^{n-1}dz$$
where $C$ is closed contour containing $z_0$. This integral and summation are principal part of coefficient of Laurent series. I guess, for any meromorphic function $f$, $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^N g(z)$$
for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and holomorphic function $g(z)$ in $\Omega$. But, I am failing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No try with $z_0=0$, $f(z)= \frac1{z(z-1)}$ and $C$ the circle of radius $2$. Then for all $n\ge 2$, $$ \int_C f(z)z^{n-1}dz= 2i\pi $$
If you meant that $0$ is the only pole of $f$ and $\Omega$ is **simply connected** then yes sure, for $n$ large enough $f(z)z^{n-1}$ is analytic on $\Omega$ and its integral on a closed-contour contained in $\Omega$  is $0$.

Comment: Oh, it was my fault. I edited it.

Comment: Me too ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can I prove  the only pole case?

Comment: To prove what ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention **simply connected** (otherwise "the only one pole" didn't make much sense)

Comment: Existence of large $n$ which makes $f(z)z^{n-1}$ is analytic.

Comment: This is the definition of $f$ has only one pole at $0$

Comment: Oops, I confused the definition. Thanks.